# AJUDA NO IONIC!

Tags: ionic, ionic3

Galera, acabei de instalar o ionic no ubuntu e ele veio na última versão, no caso a 4 (4.12.0, pra ser mais exato), como que eu posso instalar a versão 3 ? tem como fazer ?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então, você provavelmente deve ter dado um **`npm install -g ionic`** certo? Fazendo isto o npm irá buscar sempre a última versão atualizada oficialmente disponível, no caso aí **4.12.0** para você instalar uma versão anterior (fazer downgrade, contrário de upgrade) pode seguir os seguintes passos:

- **Passo 1** - Desinstalar a versão 4.12.0 instalada anteriormente com o comando

  ```
  npm uninstall -g ionic
  ```
- **Passo 2** - Instalar exatamente a versão que preferir

  ```
  npm install -g ionic@3.9.2
  ```

Isto "força" o npm a baixar e instalar exatamente esta versão.